# Properly reuse ADODB command object to execute multiple queries

Tags: c++, ado

I have to execute multiple `INSERT` queries and I wish to reuse one `Command` object instead to make new one for every query I have.

To illustrate this better here is a pseudo-code :

```
ADODB::_CommandPtr pCmd("ADODB.Command");

pCmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;

pCmd->CommandText = L"INSERT INTO MyTable ( field1, field2 ) VALUES (?,?);";

pCmd->Parameters->Append( pCmd->CreateParameter( "?", ADODB::adVarWChar,
    ADODB::adParamInput, wcslen( myString ), myString ) );

pCmd->Parameters->Append( pCmd->CreateParameter( "?", ADODB::adDouble,
    ADODB::adParamInput, sizeof(double), 
    _wtof_l( myDouble, _get_current_locale() ) ) );

pCmd->Execute( NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText );

// empty parameters collection->the problematic part

/**** execute second query **************/

pCmd->CommandText = //some other query

// and do basically the same as above:
// append some parameters and execute query
```

I do not know how to delete all parameters from `Parameters` collection so I can reuse the `Command` object for another `SQL` query.

Being inexperienced, I have tried finding the solution on the internet and found some suggestions on how to do it. Here are my tries:

```
do
{
    pCmd->Parameters->Delete(0);
}
while( pCmd->Parameters->GetCount() > 0 );
```

but failed. I have also tried this:

```
for( long i = 0; i < pCmd->Parameters->GetCount(); i++ )
    pCmd->Parameters->Delete(i);
```

but that failed too.

How can I empty `Parameters` collection properly so I can reuse the `Command` object?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: first, if your parameter setups are the same there is no reason to empty them *at all*. you can reuse them with your next set of query values. Also, you should be setting the `pCmd->CommandType` to `ADODB::adCmdText` with your current code, and you're missing a value parameter in your query (you have two in the `VALUES` list, but only one '?' in the params list). Alas back to your question, there is no `.Reset()` clause like there is in so many MS collections. The first option you show should work. I don't rec the second, and honestly rec not doing it at all unless you have a need to.

Comment: Do you know how to persist a direct parameter object reference while appending to the parameters collection so you can reuse them later for another query? If at all possible if that fits a model that works for you, by all means do it, and I'll show you how if needed.

Comment: @WhozCraig: My other queries have different parameter types and their number is different. In my post I just made a small example. I have corrected the typo and added the code snippet you suggested-thank you for your correction. I am inexperienced and do not know how to do what you have said. I hope my question is clear enough, though so you or others can answer. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: If your parameters are different, honestly you're gaining next to nothing by reusing the same command object. Were I you I would simply use a different `ADODB::_Command` object. (I've written a *freak-ton* of ADODB non-.NET code, so take that for what it is worth).

Comment: OK, I will take your advice. Just to verify if I have understood well-for every query I will need a new object, right? Still, I would like to know the answer to this question, just for the sake of my education, so I will not delete it. Thank you for your advice. Best regards.

Comment: Yes a different command object per query. So the wire-time, server time, and data transfer time, will ultimately be the same. There is a *minute* amount of client side setup of new command objects, but they're *cheap*. I wish MS would have given a native `Reset()` or `Clear()` on the parameters collection like they have on so many others non-ADO, but alas, they didn't. All the best of luck to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It seems that this code snippet works-can you verify it **since you are better developer and have more experience**: `for( long i = pCmd->Parameters->GetCount()-1; i >= 0; i-- ) pCmd->Parameters->Delete(i);` ? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: That should work. it tail-removes the collection items using a LONG for the index (which is actually xlated into a variant, but thats kinda magic that you don't need to worry about. You should make that an answer to your own question. I'll up vote it if you do.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have posted it as you have suggested. Thank you for your advices. Best regards until next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking better at the samples from the Internet I managed to figure this out. The point is to delete parameters **from end towards the beginning** like this:

```
for( long i = pCmd->Parameters->GetCount()-1; i >= 0; i-- ) 
    pCmd->Parameters->Delete(i);
```

Or like this:

```
do
{ 
    pCmd->Parameters->Delete( pCmd->Parameters->GetCount()-1 ); 
}
while( pCmd->Parameters->GetCount()-1 >= 0 );
```

I will still follow the advice given by member *WhozCraig* and create new `Command` object for every query.

Thanks again *WhozCraig* and best regards until next time!